# how avoid attribute-centric column must not come after a non-attribute-centric sibling in XML without null

Tags: sql, xml

I need to have a xml with a structure to use in erp  something like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ProcessProjectBudget releaseID="9.2">
       <DataArea>
          <Process>
             <Tenant>infor</Tenant>
           </Process>
          <ProjectBudget>
             <IDs>
                <ID>IMP000120</ID>
             </IDs>
             <BudgetDetail>
                <ID>E_2_IMP000120_102             _0000_2</ID>
                <Item>
                   <ItemID>
                      <ID>KD039</ID>
                   </ItemID>
                </Item>
                <UserArea>
                   <Property>
                      <NameValue name="tpptc120.pric">56200.0000</NameValue>
                   </Property>
                   <Property>
                      <NameValue name="tpptc120.cdf_pcom">180000.0000</NameValue>
                   </Property>
                   <Property>
                      <NameValue name="tpptc120.cdf_pcos">1200.000</NameValue>
                   </Property>
                </UserArea>
             </BudgetDetail>
          </ProjectBudget>
       </DataArea>
    </ProcessProjectBudget>
```

the query that  I use read from different table and some data are repeating
tag name is userarea

```
 SELECT
        'infor' as 'Process/Tenant',
        o.LNProject as [ProjectBudget / IDs / ID],
        (
            SELECT
                'E_2_' + o.LNProject + '_' + ol.Label + ' 0001' as [ID],
                ol.ERPPartNumber as [Item / ItemID / ID],
                'tpptc120.pric' AS [UserArea / Property / NameValue / @name],
                isnull(ol.CostoItem, 0) AS [UserArea / Property / NameValue],
                null,
                'tpptc120.cdf_pcom' AS [UserArea / Property / NameValue / @name],
                isnull(ol.PrezzoItem, 0) AS [UserArea / Property / NameValue],
                null,
                'tpptc120.cdf_pcos' AS [UserArea / Property / NameValue / @name],
                isnull(ol.PrezzoLordoItem, 1) AS [UserArea / Property / NameValue] 
            FROM
                Exp_OrderSubLines AS ol 
            WHERE
                ol.OrderNO = o.OrderNO 
            order by
                ol.[LineNo] FOR XML PATH('BudgetDetail'), TYPE,      elements 
        )
        AS ProjectBudget 
    FROM
        Exp_Orders AS o 
    where
        o.TargetOrderNo = 'SOB000014' 
        FOR XML PATH('DataArea'), elements, type;
```

The result repeat tag userArea  and i cannot use in my parse

```
<ProcessProjectBudget releaseID="9.2">
   <DataArea>
      <Process>
         <Tenant>infor</Tenant>
       </Process>
      <ProjectBudget>
         <IDs>
            <ID>IMP000120</ID>
         </IDs>
         <BudgetDetail>
            <ID>E_2_IMP000120_102             _0000_2</ID>
            <Item>
               <ItemID>
                  <ID>KD039</ID>
               </ItemID>
            </Item>
            <UserArea>
               <Property>
                  <NameValue name="tpptc120.pric">56200.0000</NameValue>
               </Property>
            </UserArea>
            <UserArea>
               <Property>
                  <NameValue name="tpptc120.cdf_pcom">180000.0000</NameValue>
               </Property>
            </UserArea>
            <UserArea>
               <Property>
                  <NameValue name="tpptc120.cdf_pcos">1200.000</NameValue>
               </Property>
            </UserArea>
         </BudgetDetail>
      </ProjectBudget>
   </DataArea>
</ProcessProjectBudget>
```

but after that i cannot use tag user area for all elements

I dont find a solution using sql